# Combine two functions into one

Tags: python, coordinates, gis

I have two functions. One of them returns a list which contains a sublists of coordinates from an input value. The other returns a buffer around those coordinates as a dictionary. I want to simplify those functions and maybe combine them in some way.

```
buffer = 300

def coordinates(k_leht):
   x1 = int(k_leht[-3:]) * 1000
   y1 = int(k_leht[:3]) * 1000 + 6000000
   x2 = x1 + 1000
   y2 = y1 + 1000

   return [[x1, y1], [x2, y1], [x2, y2], [x1, y2], [x1, y1]]

def coordinates_buffer(k_leht):
   # Coordinates are created the same way as in the previous function
   x1 = int(k_leht[-3:]) * 1000
   y1 = int(k_leht[:3]) * 1000 + 6000000
   x2 = x1 + 1000
   y2 = y1 + 1000

   # Buffers around the coordinates
   x1_puhv = x1 - buffer
   y1_puhv = y1 - buffer
   x2_puhv = x2 + buffer
   y2_puhv = y2 + buffer

   return {'x1_puhv': x1_puhv, 'y1_puhv': y1_puhv, 'x2_puhv': x2_puhv, 'y2_puhv': y2_puhv}
```

Comment: just factor out the first couple of lines into an `extract_coordinates` function returning x1, y1, x2, y2? Then remove the duplicate parts and replace them with a call to `extract_coordinates(k_leht)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid useless repetition of codes you could do something like this :

```
def coordinates_list_or_dict(k_leht, dict = False):
    x1 = int(k_leht[-3:]) * 1000
    y1 = int(k_leht[:3]) * 1000 + 6000000
    x2 = x1 + 1000
    y2 = y1 + 1000
   
    if (not dict): return [[x1, y1], [x2, y1], [x2, y2], [x1, y2], [x1, y1]]
    else:
        x1_puhv = x1 - buffer
        y1_puhv = y1 - buffer
        x2_puhv = x2 + buffer
        y2_puhv = y2 + buffer
        return {'x1_puhv': x1_puhv, 'y1_puhv': y1_puhv, 'x2_puhv': x2_puhv, 'y2_puhv': y2_puhv}

coordinates_buffer_or_list(k)       #=> return list
coordinates_buffer_or_list(k, True) #=> return dictionary
```

Another solution would be to put the four first lines in an independent function and use it as a helper function in the two original functions.